# C# winforms - How to combine scrollbar with mouse wheel zooming?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, mouseevent, gdi+

**Problem** - I'm writing a program that draws graphics, and zooming is one of the features. Currently, a `picturebox` is placed on a `panel`, and the `picturebox` has vertical and horizontal scroll bars on the right and bottom. How to combine scrollbar with mouse wheel zooming? And I'm not sure if I should use `paint` to draw the graphics or set a bitmap to draw the graphics onto it?

**Expected** - When the mouse wheel is scrolled, the entire canvas(`picturebox`) include drawn graphics are scaled according to the current mouse position as the center (the horizontal and vertical scroll bars change according to the zoom center). When the mouse wheel is pressed and moved, the canvas can be dragged freely.

Expected as follows:
[image]

**The initial code**

```
private List<Point> _points;
private int _pointRadius = 50;
private float _scale = 1f;
private float _offsetX = 0f;
private float _offsetY = 0f;

private void picturebox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _points.Add(e.Location);
}

private void picturebox_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEvnetArgs e)
{
    if(e.Delta < 0)
    {
        _scale += 0.1f;
        _offsetX = e.X * (1f - _scale);
        _offsetY = e.X * (1f - _scale);
    }
    else
    {
        _scale -= 0.1f;
        _offsetX = e.X * (1f - _scale);
        _offsetY = e.X * (1f - _scale);
    }
    picturebox.Invalidate();
}

private void picturebox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(_offsetX, _offsetY);
    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(_scaleX, _scaleY);
    foreach (Point p in _points)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, p.X, - _pointRadius, p.Y - _pointRadius, 2 * _pointRadius, 2 * _pointRadius);
    }
}
```

Hope the answer is modified based on the initial code.

Thanks in advance to everyone who helped me.

Comment: If you use the `Paint` event there is no need to use a `PictureBox`, a pure control will do it. The scrollbar adjustment is not trivial at all. Feel free to look at my [`ImageViewer`](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing.Tools/blob/master/KGySoft.Drawing.ImagingTools/View/Controls/ImageViewer.cs#L311) control. Zooming triggers an `Invalidate(InvalidateFlags.Sizes)`, which ends up calling the `AdjustSizes` where scrollbar visibility and positions are adjusted respecting the zoom, location, DPI and possible right-to-left layout.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg I looked at your [ImageViewer](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing.Tools/blob/master/KGySoft.Drawing.ImagingTools/View/Controls/ImageViewer.cs#L311). It gave me some inspiration. Would it be easier if I drew the graphics on a Bitmap?

Comment: Not necessarily because it may make things complicated: you either always need to allocate a new bitmap when zooming (which may consume a _lot_ of memory), or the image gets blurry/pixelated. In my case it was alright because it _is_ an image viewer after all. So I would stick to graphics transforms for such a task you posted in the recording.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg I looked at your [ImageViewer](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing.Tools/blob/master/KGySoft.Drawing.ImagingTools/View/Controls/ImageViewer.cs#L311) but I'm not completely clear. Would you mind modifying my initial code directly? If that's so, I'll be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be easier if I drew the graphics on a Bitmap?

Considering the nature of your task and the already implemented solutions in my `ImageViewer` I created a solution that draws the result in a `Metafile`, which is both elegant, consumes minimal memory and allows zooming without quality issues.

Here is the stripped version of my `ImageViewer:`

```cs
public class MetafileViewer : Control
{
    private HScrollBar sbHorizontal = new HScrollBar { Visible = false };
    private VScrollBar sbVertical = new VScrollBar { Visible = false };
    private Metafile? image;
    private Size imageSize;
    private Rectangle targetRectangle;
    private Rectangle clientRectangle;
    private float zoom = 1;
    private bool sbHorizontalVisible;
    private bool sbVerticalVisible;
    private int scrollFractionVertical;

    public MetafileViewer()
    {
        Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { sbHorizontal, sbVertical });
        sbHorizontal.ValueChanged += ScrollbarValueChanged;
        sbVertical.ValueChanged += ScrollbarValueChanged;
    }

    void ScrollbarValueChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e) => Invalidate();

    public Metafile? Image
    {
        get => image;
        set
        {
            image = value;
            imageSize = image?.Size ?? default;
            InvalidateLayout();
        }
    }

    public bool TryTranslate(Point mouseCoord, out PointF canvasCoord)
    {
        canvasCoord = default;
        if (!targetRectangle.Contains(mouseCoord))
            return false;
        canvasCoord = new PointF((mouseCoord.X - targetRectangle.X) / zoom, (mouseCoord.Y - targetRectangle.Y) / zoom);
        if (sbHorizontalVisible)
            canvasCoord.X += sbHorizontal.Value / zoom;
        if (sbVerticalVisible)
            canvasCoord.Y += sbVertical.Value / zoom;

        return true;
    }

    private void InvalidateLayout()
    {
        Invalidate();
        if (imageSize.IsEmpty)
        {
            sbHorizontal.Visible = sbVertical.Visible = sbHorizontalVisible = sbVerticalVisible = false;
            targetRectangle = Rectangle.Empty;
            return;
        }

        Size clientSize = ClientSize;
        if (clientSize.Width < 1 || clientSize.Height < 1)
        {
            targetRectangle = Rectangle.Empty;
            return;
        }

        Size scaledSize = imageSize.Scale(zoom);

        // scrollbars visibility
        sbHorizontalVisible = scaledSize.Width > clientSize.Width
            || scaledSize.Width > clientSize.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth && scaledSize.Height > clientSize.Height;
        sbVerticalVisible = scaledSize.Height > clientSize.Height
            || scaledSize.Height > clientSize.Height - SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight && scaledSize.Width > clientSize.Width;

        if (sbHorizontalVisible)
            clientSize.Height -= SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight;
        if (sbVerticalVisible)
            clientSize.Width -= SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
        if (clientSize.Width < 1 || clientSize.Height < 1)
        {
            targetRectangle = Rectangle.Empty;
            return;
        }

        Point clientLocation = Point.Empty;
        var targetLocation = new Point((clientSize.Width >> 1) - (scaledSize.Width >> 1),
            (clientSize.Height >> 1) - (scaledSize.Height >> 1));

        // both scrollbars
        if (sbHorizontalVisible && sbVerticalVisible)
        {
            sbHorizontal.Dock = sbVertical.Dock = DockStyle.None;
            sbHorizontal.Width = clientSize.Width;
            sbHorizontal.Top = clientSize.Height;
            sbHorizontal.Left = 0;
            sbVertical.Height = clientSize.Height;
            sbVertical.Left = clientSize.Width;
        }
        // horizontal scrollbar
        else if (sbHorizontalVisible)
            sbHorizontal.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        // vertical scrollbar
        else if (sbVerticalVisible)
            sbVertical.Dock = DockStyle.Right;

        // adjust scrollbar values
        if (sbHorizontalVisible)
        {
            sbHorizontal.Minimum = targetLocation.X;
            sbHorizontal.Maximum = targetLocation.X + scaledSize.Width;
            sbHorizontal.LargeChange = clientSize.Width;
            sbHorizontal.SmallChange = 32;
            sbHorizontal.Value = Math.Min(sbHorizontal.Value, sbHorizontal.Maximum - sbHorizontal.LargeChange);
        }

        if (sbVerticalVisible)
        {
            sbVertical.Minimum = targetLocation.Y;
            sbVertical.Maximum = targetLocation.Y + scaledSize.Height;
            sbVertical.LargeChange = clientSize.Height;
            sbVertical.SmallChange = 32;
            sbVertical.Value = Math.Min(sbVertical.Value, sbVertical.Maximum - sbVertical.LargeChange);
        }

        sbHorizontal.Visible = sbHorizontalVisible;
        sbVertical.Visible = sbVerticalVisible;

        clientRectangle = new Rectangle(clientLocation, clientSize);
        targetRectangle = new Rectangle(targetLocation, scaledSize);
        if (sbVerticalVisible)
            clientRectangle.X = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        InvalidateLayout();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if (image == null || e.ClipRectangle.Width <= 0 || e.ClipRectangle.Height <= 0)
            return;

        if (targetRectangle.IsEmpty)
            InvalidateLayout();
        if (targetRectangle.IsEmpty)
            return;

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.IntersectClip(clientRectangle);
        Rectangle dest = targetRectangle;
        if (sbHorizontalVisible)
            dest.X -= sbHorizontal.Value;
        if (sbVerticalVisible)
            dest.Y -= sbVertical.Value;
        g.DrawImage(image, dest);
        g.DrawRectangle(SystemPens.ControlText, Rectangle.Inflate(targetRectangle, 1, 1));
    }

    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
        switch (ModifierKeys)
        {
            // zoom
            case Keys.Control:
                float delta = (float)e.Delta / SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollDelta / 5;
                if (delta.Equals(0f))
                    return;
                delta += 1;
                SetZoom(zoom * delta);
                break;

            // vertical scroll
            case Keys.None:
                VerticalScroll(e.Delta);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void VerticalScroll(int delta)
    {
        // When scrolling by mouse, delta is always +-120 so this will be a small change on the scrollbar.
        // But we collect the fractional changes caused by the touchpad scrolling so it will not be lost either.
        int totalDelta = scrollFractionVertical + delta * sbVertical.SmallChange;
        scrollFractionVertical = totalDelta % SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollDelta;
        int newValue = sbVertical.Value - totalDelta / SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollDelta;
        SetValueSafe(sbVertical, newValue);
    }

    internal static void SetValueSafe(ScrollBar scrollBar, int value)
    {
        if (value < scrollBar.Minimum)
            value = scrollBar.Minimum;
        else if (value > scrollBar.Maximum - scrollBar.LargeChange + 1)
            value = scrollBar.Maximum - scrollBar.LargeChange + 1;

        scrollBar.Value = value;
    }

    private void SetZoom(float value)
    {
        const float maxZoom = 10f;
        float minZoom = image == null ? 1f : 1f / Math.Min(imageSize.Width, imageSize.Height);
        if (value < minZoom)
            value = minZoom;

        if (value > maxZoom)
            value = maxZoom;

        if (zoom.Equals(value))
            return;

        zoom = value;
        InvalidateLayout();
    }
}
```

And then the updated version of your initial code (add a new point by right click, zoom by Ctrl + mouse scroll):

```cs
public partial class RenderMetafileForm : Form
{
    private static Size canvasSize = new Size(300, 200);
    private List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
    private const float pointRadius = 5;

    public RenderMetafileForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        metafileViewer.MouseClick += MetafileViewer_MouseClick;
        UpdateMetafile();
    }

    private void MetafileViewer_MouseClick(object? sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && metafileViewer.TryTranslate(e.Location, out var coord))
        {
            points.Add(coord);
            UpdateMetafile();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateMetafile()
    {
        Graphics refGraph = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
        IntPtr hdc = refGraph.GetHdc();
        Metafile result;
        try
        {
            result = new Metafile(hdc, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, canvasSize), MetafileFrameUnit.Pixel, EmfType.EmfOnly, "Canvas");
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {
                foreach (PointF point in points)
                    g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Navy, point.X - pointRadius, point.Y - pointRadius, pointRadius * 2, pointRadius * 2);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            refGraph.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
            refGraph.Dispose();
        }

        Metafile? previous = metafileViewer.Image;
        metafileViewer.Image = result;
        previous?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Metafile rendering with zooming]

> ⚠️ **Note:** I did not add panning by keyboard or by grabbing the image but you can extract those from the original [`ImageViewer`](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing.Tools/blob/master/KGySoft.Drawing.ImagingTools/View/Controls/ImageViewer.cs). Also, I removed DPI-aware scaling but see the `ScaleSize` extensions in the linked project.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it looks perfect. Did you create a custom control  `MetafileViewer `? So that `picturebox` and `panel` are no longer needed, right?

Comment: That's right, `MetafileViewer` is your new `PictureBox`

Comment: I ran your answer up. Your answer solved my problem almost perfectly, but the only remaining problem is zooming with the cursor as the zoom center. Can we do it? ? If you can, please edit your answer so that it perfectly solves my problem. thanks.

Comment: Your original question has been answered here. If you are unable to adjust the behavior for your preferences, ask a new question, demonstrating what you tried and what did go wrong. I'm afraid I will not be able to answer questions for a few weeks now but hopefully others will be quicker than me.